# mysql YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, datetime

Does mysql understand correctly `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'` format for dateTime type?
I have a few date fields which comes from xml (with type xsd:dateTime `'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss'` format). Then I need to save these field into DB (mysql dateTime format is `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` ) Should I convert xml`s date format to mysq date format ? Or can I just insert these fields into the DB without converting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('2010-12-30T01:02:03' AS datetime);
+-----------------------------------------+
| CAST('2010-12-30T01:02:03' AS datetime) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2010-12-30 01:02:03                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> SELECT CAST('2010-12-30 01:02:03' AS datetime);
+-----------------------------------------+
| CAST('2010-12-30 01:02:03' AS datetime) |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 2010-12-30 01:02:03                     |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: i have similar problem my table structure is                                      create table badges (
  Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  UserId INT,
  Name VARCHAR(50),
  CreationDate datetime
);   I have date fields which comes from xml (with type 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss' format). when i load xml it was loading null values for this column...pls suggest how to get values in to mysql db?

Comment: @DeviKiran Please post your problem as separate question, with detailed explanation of how exactly you load XML files into columns and how you do typecast, as shown above.