# MySql YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS to time

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a table with a varchar column DateFrom that has this format:

2014-02-22T08:08:00

I want an sql that prints 08:08 and one that prints 22-02-2014 but i can't seem to get the time function to work.

What i'm trying to do is get all entries in DateFrom and print them as just time (HH:MM)
and the same with date.

Comment: So you want the date and time separated?

Comment: Fine but why not storing that in the database as DateTime format instead of varchar? Also.. what do you want? a PHP function or what?

Comment: Which time function? What exactly have you tried? What exactly was the outcome of your try? Which specification does the format you use inside that varchar column follow? Which Mysql Server Version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563049/mysql-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss)

Comment: It is not my table. It's a table that i have to work with and i need to  be able to just get the time from this string

Comment: That's outlined in the linked duplicate exactly, my answer below is a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not looking for [date/time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) but for string functions, they are available here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

One string function that I think is useful for your substring operation is [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr). You can tell per the varchar column that you want a sub-string starting from a position for a certain length with it:

```
SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 1 FOR 8) AS DateName -- "2014-02-22"
SUBSTRING(DateFrom FROM 10 FOR 5) AS TimeName -- "08:08"
```

Use other string functions to concatenate parts in the order you need it.

Alternatively you can [cast your varchar string in that format to a datetime type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4563049/367456) and then format as needed:

```
CAST(DateFrom AS datetime)
```

See the Mysql manual for more information about casting types and the date-time functions that are available:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

SQL Example:

```
SET @DateFrom = '2014-02-22T08:08:00';
SELECT DATE(CAST(@DateFrom AS datetime)); -- '2014-02-22'
SELECT TIME(CAST(@DateFrom AS datetime)); -- '08:08:00'
```

Answer (score 3):

Altough I think string functions are a better option in this case (like @hakre answered) and less cpu expensive, you can also achieve this goal using the `STR_TO_DATE`, `DATE` and `TIME` function.

```
SELECT 
DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2014-02-22T08:08:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')),
    TIME(STR_TO_DATE('2014-02-22T08:08:00', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'))
```